# php class not responding

Tags: php, oop

I have a problem with the following piece of PHP script:

```
<?php
abstract class root {
protected $con;
protected $sql;
protected $query;
protected $row;

protected function __construct__() {
    require_once("db.settings.php");

    $this->con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8", $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    mysql_close($this->con);
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->con);
}

protected function __destruct__() {
    mysql_close($this->con);
    unset($this->con);
}

    }

    class users extends root {
private $h;

public function __construct__() {
    parent::__construct__();
}

public function __destruct__() {
    parent::__destruct__();
}

public function register($uname, $pass, $mail, $name) {
    $this->hash = sha1($uname . md5($pass) . $name);

    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO users (user, pass, mail, name, hash) VALUES ($uname, $pass, $mail, $name, $this->hash)";
    mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    mysql_close($this->con);

    return true;
}

public function login($uname, $pass) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = $uname AND pass = " . md5($pass);
    mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));

    if(mysql_num_rows !== 1){
        mysql_close($this->con);

        return false;
    } else {
        setcookie("who", $uname, time() + 3600);
        $this->h = md5($pass);
        setcookie("token", $this->h, time() + 3600);
        $this->h = sha1($uname . md5($pass));
        setcookie("hash", $uname, time() + 3600);

        return true;
    }
}

public function logout() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['who']) && isset($_COOKIE['token']) && isset($_COOKIE['hash']) && $_COOKIE['hash'] == sha1($_COOKIE['who'] . $_COOKIE['token'])) {
        setcookie("who", $uname, time() - 1);
        setcookie("token", $uname, time() - 1);
        setcookie("hash", $uname, time() - 1);

        return true;
    } else {
        setcookie("who", $uname, time() - 1);
        setcookie("token", $uname, time() - 1);
        setcookie("hash", $uname, time() - 1);

        return false;
    }
}

public function check() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['who']) && isset($_COOKIE['token']) && isset($_COOKIE['hash']) && $_COOKIE['hash'] == sha1($_COOKIE['who'] . $_COOKIE['token'])) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
    }

    class iPhone extends root {
private $hash;
public $content = array();
private $j = 0;

public function __construct__() {
    parent::__construct__();
}

public function __destruct__() {
    parent::__destruct__();
}

public function registerIphone() {
    # implented later
    $this->hash = md5(time);

    $this->sql = "UPDATE users SET phoneid = " . $this->hash . " WHERE user = " . $_COOKIE['who'];
    mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    setcookie("phoneid", $this->hash, 1314000);

    return true;
}
public function checkIphone() {
    # implented later

    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phoneid = " . $_COOKIE['phoneid'] . " LIMIT 1";
    if(mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
public function deleteIphone($who) {
    # implented later

    $this->sql = "UPDATE users SET phoneid = '' WHERE user = $who";
    if(mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public function showContent($what) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE articleName = " . $what . " AND media = Handheld";
    $this->query = mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    while($this->row = mysql_fetch_array($this->query)) {
        $content[$j]['id']          = $row['id'];
        $content[$j]['date']        = $row['date'];
        $content[$j]['articleName'] = $row['articleName'];
        $content[$j]['content']     = $row['content'];

        $this->j++;
    }
    mysql_close($this->con);
    return $this->content;
}
    }

    class contentManager extends root {
public $content = array();
private $j = 0;

public function __construct__() {
    parent::__construct__();
}

public function __destruct__() {
    parent::__destruct__();
}

public function showContent($what) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE articleName = $what AND media = Browser";
    $this->query = mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    while($this->row = mysql_fetch_array($this->query)) {
        $content[$j]['id']          = $row['id'];
        $content[$j]['date']        = $row['date'];
        $content[$j]['articleName'] = $row['articleName'];
        $content[$j]['content']     = $row['content'];

        $this->j++;
    }
    mysql_close($this->con);
    return $this->content;
}

public function editContent($id, $articlename, $content) {
    $this->sql = "UPDATE content SET articleName = $articlename, content = $content WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));

    return true;
}

public function deleteContent($id) {
    $this->sql = "DELETE FROM content WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));

    return true;
}
    }

    class map extends root {
private $j = 0;
private $key = "my google maps api key";
private $address;
private $helper;
private $page;
private $xml;
private $longitude;
private $latitude;
private $altitude;

public function __construct__() {
    parent::__construct__();
}

public function __destruct__() {
    parent::__destruct__();
}

public function getMarkers() {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM markers";
    $this->query = mysql_query($this->sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    while($this->row = mysql_fetch_array($this->query)) {
        if($this->j < (mysql_num_rows($this->query) -1 )){
            print("['" . $this->row['address'] . "', " . $this->row['lat'] . ", " . $this->row['lng'] . ", 1],");
            $this->j++;
        } else {
            print("['" . $this->row['address'] . "', " . $this->row['lat'] . ", " . $this->row['lng'] . ", 1]");
            $this->j++;

        }
    }

}

public function setMarkers($addr) {
    $this->helper = str_replace(" ", "+", $addr);
    $this->helper = explode(",", $this->helper);
    $this->address = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=$this->helper[0],+$this->helper[1],+$this->helper[2]&output=xml&key=$this->key";
    $this->page = file_get_contents($this->address);
    $this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->page);
    list($this->longitude, $this->latitude, $this->altitude) = explode(",", $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates);

    echo $this->longitude . " :: " . $this->latitude;



}

public function deleteMarkers($id) {
    /*
    ***  FUNCTION NOT YET IMPLENTED!
      */
}
    }

    ?>
```

For those, who do not want to read source: I create an abstract class, that creates database connection, then other classes, like login extends it, using the parents database connection.

The problem is, whenever I create an instance of a class, like:

```
$map = new map();
```

Then try to do something with the instance:

```
$map->setMarkers("");
```

Nothing happens. Literally nothing. No error message, and no output.

All help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  e.g. adding `print` statements to find out where it gets stuck?

Comment: Yep, tried to print strings from the root and from the child classes constructors && destructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some incorrect function definitions:

`protected function __construct__() {`

should read

`protected function __construct() {`

The same is true for the `__destruct__()` function - this should read `__destruct()`

However you should certainly be receiving some error reporting - try setting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the top of the script.

Comment: I thought I knew the syntax of this... ty ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, check the return values of each of the mysql function calls. They all return valuable information. For example, mysql_connect():

Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

Also, in your constructor, you're closing the database connection before selecting the DB, which doesn't really make sense. Remove this line:

```
mysql_close($this->con);
```

and see what happens. Actually, on second read, remove that call from all functions except the destructor. It might not even be necessary there, since DB connections are closed on script termination, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor :

```
protected function __construct() {
    require_once("db.settings.php");

    $this->con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8", $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
    mysql_close($this->con);
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->con);
}
```

remove close connection, you closing connector on destruct ... it should be like following :

```
protected function __construct() {
        require_once("db.settings.php");

        $this->con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
        mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8", $this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->con);
    }

Change construct and destruct to right ones : __destruct__() to __destruct() same with construct ...
```

Comment: You might want to change the method name too.

Comment: I use abstract because I don't want the root class to be instanced by itself, just when some child class is using its database connection.

Comment: sory made some edits .. it was copied from what you wrote .. call constructor as following __construct($methods)

Comment: Wish I could give all of you guys vote ups, but I don't have enough reputation. The right answer goes to Andy, since he pointed out a syntax error, that caused all of the problems. Thilo & Max Sobol, thank you guys too, I wish my coworkers were professionals like you guys.